# reading a session attribute in jsp

Tags: jsp, session-variables

i am setting a session attribute in a servlet called cartList which is an array of strings like this,

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("cartList", items);
```

where items is an array of objects of type String.

In a jsp, i'm calling the above attribute like this,

```
line123:String[] cartItems = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("cartList");
line124:for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
    line125:String[] cartItem = cartItems[i].split("\\|");
```

cartItems[i] will never be empty and will contain a string like this,[AAA-000|2].

I'm getting an exception at line 125 which is a nullpointerexception. I have no idea why i'm getting this error. I'm checking the contents of 'items' in the servlet, its fine and not empty. 
I have spent a whole day trying to solve this. I'm at my wit's end! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you sure in jsp value is fetched correctly? also in jsp you have a built in session variable no need to write request.getSession();

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response. I don't know if the value is fetched correctly in the jsp. How do i check that? i thought request.getSession() was the only way to access the session attribute. wouldn't I need the session object to access a session attribute and to get the session object don't I have to do request.getSession()?

Comment: @user686997: to check just simply put `System.out.println(carItems);` after fetching the value from session in jsp.

Comment: yes, the value is fetched correctly.

Comment: @user The problem is not that you are not getting cartItems. The problem is that some values of cartItems contain null. If cartItems was null, it should have had thrown NullPointerException at cartItems.length in for loop.

Comment: @user686997, @craftsman: I was also thinking the same thats why I asked OP to check whether values is fetched correctly or not.

Comment: Thank you guys. I figured out the problem. I was setting the size of items as 10 and thats why there were null values in cartItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are not getting `cartItems` from session. The problem is that some values of `cartItems` contain null. Before invoking `split()`, print the value of `cartItems[i]` to see what it is carrying.

```
String[] cartItems = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("cartList");
for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
    out.println("cartItems["+i+"]: "+cartItems[i]);
    String[] cartItem = null;
    if(cartItems[i]!=null)
        cartItem = cartItems[i].split("\\|");
}
```

If you see `null` for some values, go back to your servlet and make sure you assign them some value before putting them into `cartList`.

Comment: @craftsmen: your code snippet helped me realise that there were null values in the array. I have fixed it now. Thank you!

Comment: @sherry you are welcome :) By the way, just a suggestion: using debugger in such cases is very helpful and saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use a debugger? i have been using print statements so far..

Comment: I would highly recommend to use an IDE. It greatly increases a programmer's efficiency. For beginners, NetBeans is good. Its simple, intuitive and easy to start with. Once you are comfortable with Java, switch to Eclipse. You can find by googling loads of tutorials on debugging with NetBeans and Eclipse.